# Algorithm for distributing images to form a square

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm building an application that creates a spritesheet from a series of images. Currently the application requires to indicate the number of columns by the user but I would like to add an option that suggests this parameter automatically which allows to obtain an almost square spritesheet.
If the images were square, a square root of the total number of images would suffice but this is not the case.
The images must all be the same size but may be taller than wide or the opposite.
For example: the sprite sheet has a walking character and each image is 331 high and 160 wide. The number of frames is 25.
I should find an algorithm that suggests the number of columns (and rows) that allows me to obtain a sheet that is as square as possible.
Unfortunately I have no code to present just because I have no idea what kind of reasoning to do.
Do you have any suggestions to work on?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this in fact is a pure maths problem. It has nothing to do with Delphi and FreePascal. You could ask the same question in the C# or Python tag and obtain exactly the same answers.

Comment: And does this seem like a relevant answer to the question? Yes, you are right, it is pure mathematics, but applied to a specific language such as pascal. Where is the problem?

Comment: I have not posted an answer. I posted a comment on your question. And the point of my comment is that a pure maths question is best posed without a very particular applied context. At least that is my strong belief after 10 years in academia. I might also add that I have neither downvoted nor close-voted your Q. (Also, a person asking the same maths Q but in the C# context might not find this Q, because (s)he might not think about searching the Delphi tag. And so on.)

Comment: I am truly sorry that you feel that way. Text-based communication is difficult. If we had been in the same room talking, I would have been able to show you with my body language and the tone and melody of my voice, when I made my first comment, that I very much didn't want to sound harsh. I only wanted to give you some constructive feedback on how to write a good question. That's what the comment section should be used for.

Comment: Okay, I try to understand what you want to communicate to me, but I have some difficulties. Which tag should I use? What would have been the right way to ask for help on a a topic like this? Sorry but why, HERE, everything has to be so complicated?

Comment: Actually, since this is a pure mathematics question, you will probably get better answers at the Mathematics stack exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/. And then any Assembly, Pascal, C++, Python, or Fortran developer looking for such an algorithm can find that maths Q and its answers! :)

Comment: The question is fine now with the `algorithm` tag. No need to ask on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Okay guys, hugs, thanks anyway for your comments. But maybe someone should be wondering why Stack Overflow has some problems lately (and those who participated in the last election say so)

Comment: Well, you got two high-quality answers within an hour of posting your Q. That's not that bad, is it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is that, if the image height is twice the width, you will need twice more columns than rows.

If:

- q is the image ratio (width/height)
- c is the number of columns
- r is the number of rows
- n is the total number of images

then we have:

r / c = q and r * c = n

After a few substitutions:

- c = sqrt(n / q)
- r = q * c

In your case, q = 160 / 331 = 0.48

c = sqrt(25 / 0.48) = 7.2

r = 0.48 * c = 3.5

So (after rounding) the answer is 4 rows and 7 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, this is an interesting question.

I don't have time to think about it extensively, but here are my two cents:

Let the width and height of the sprites be *w* and *h*, respectively, and let the number of sprites be *n*.

If you put these in a grid consisting of *c* columns and *r* rows, the total width of the grid will be *cw*  and the total height *rh*. You want the quotient *cw*/*rh* to be as close to 1 as possible.

Now, if you chose *c*  and *r* freely, the number of grid cells, *N := cr*, might well be slightly larger than *n*. In most cases, I would expect you to accept a partially empty last row.

Since *N* is close to *n*,

[image: Equation 1]

Hence, we want to find *c* such that

[image: Equation 2]

is as small as possible. Clearly this happens when

[image: Equation 3]

Hence, if you let the number of columns be √(*nh*/*w*) rounded to the nearest integer, you will probably get a fairly square grid.